# I want to use disabled and enabled function with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, frontend

When I write x1 at my textbox and push the button, an alert occurs. And because of that the coupon had been used, after I shut down the alert , textbox and button becomes disabled

I append the Remove Coupon text to the near it and when I click the Remove Coupon text, the textbox and button becomes enabled. However, when I click the button for the second time, it appends to the near of Remove Coupon text secondly. When I remove the Remove Coupon and enable it, How can I apply the process for again and again?

Here are my codes and demo;

```
<input type="text" id="couponInput" class="couponInput" placeholder="Coupon code" />                                                 
<button type="button" id="couponApply" class="couponApply">APPLY COUPON</button>                           
<span class="removeCoupon"></span>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.couponApply').click(function(event){
       var couponInputval = $(".couponInput").val();

       if(couponInputval == "x1"){
          alert('Coupon Applied!');
          $( ".removeCoupon" ).append( "Remove Coupon" );
          $(".couponInput, .couponApply").attr('disabled','disabled');          

          $('.removeCoupon').click(function(){
            $(".couponInput, .couponApply").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');            
          });
       }
       else{
         alert('Error');
       }
       event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/509yp6k0/

Comment: you should use `.prop()` to set the `disabled` boolean attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.removeCoupon').on('click', function(){ 
    $(".couponInput, .couponApply").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(this).empty();
});
```

Comment: FYI that's not a delegate

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood what you're asking, you just need to remove the `Remove coupon` text from the `span` upon removing the coupon. You can do this using `empty()`:

```
$('.removeCoupon').click(function () {
    $(".couponInput, .couponApply").prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).empty();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/509yp6k0/4/)